# htaccess routing http to https sometimes includes removed CodeIgniter 'index.php'. Why?

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, https

I have the following mod rewrite rules - the first to remove the 'index.php' segment from URI requests and the second to force a HTTPS connection. However the second is reinserting the 'index.php'.

```
# send request via index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

# force SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  \.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

For example -

> http://www.mysite.tld/somepage

becomes

> https://www.mysite.tld/index.php?/somepage

I'm still trying to understand how to write htaccess files but is there a way to combine these two to avoid this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to swap the order of your rules.

```
# force SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  \.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# send request via index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

When the redirect rule was last, it was still being applied because the first rule gets applied, rewriting stops for that iteration, then the rewrite engine loops, then the second rule gets applied and the URI (which now contains an `index.php`) gets redirected.

Comment: I tried that but it stopped forcing HTTPS. I get your logic though so I'm not really sure why!

Comment: I'm afraid even with those flags, it's not forcing HTTPS. Any other ideas why?

Comment: @dieselpower44 Dunno, works perfectly fine in my test install, with a blank htaccess file.

Comment: Surely {REQUEST_FILENAME} is still the same from the initial request? So even if we change it to https:// that variable is still http://? Or is the {REQUEST_FILENAME} variable actually changed by rewrite?

Comment: @dieselpower44 `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` doesn't matter whether it's http or https, it's the file/directory that apache thinks the URI currently maps to

Comment: I see what's the matter - it *is* rewriting the URI but it seems to be rewriting it after HTTPS would be handled? As in, the URI is 'https' but the browser isn't showing the HTTPS connection icon. Did you see that behavior with your test install?

Comment: @dieselpower44 No, if the scheme is `https://`, then the browser would automatically attempt to connect to port 443, the SSL port, and negotiate an SSL handshake. If there's a way to make the browser display `https://` but not go through an SSL connection, that's a **very** serious security risk. My test bed works fine, I get redirected immediately to SSL , I don't see any index.php in the URI

Comment: You're right, it does work. It works for all pages except the one I'd been testing on so there must be something else going wrong. Sorry to doubt and thanks for the help and follow-ups.

Comment: In case you or anyone else is interested, the issue was that I was requesting http content (Google Fonts to be specific) within the file which was making the browser not display the HTTPS badge - presumably this is deliberate to protect users.